# Mail forwarder or something like that

Tags: mail-forwarding

I don't know where to start for searching this thing.
I need a simple server that act like an SMTP server, accept all incoming email from every ip, every address, every everything, and forward the email to a single email address, to a single smtp server, from a single name.
I have googled a bunch of searches, email forwarder, email relay mta agent, .... but nothing that can do this.
The goal is to create a simple server that accept all the incoming mail system alerts from various server on many private farm networks and forward all this mails to a real smtp enterprise server (indoor) to my personal enterprise mail address.

Comment: I's easy to configure Postfix like this.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a "catchall".

sendmail can do this on linux - I'd use a ".forward" file to keep a local copy as well as forward one to your enterprise machine.

You're probably going to want to re-originate those mails (hence the above suggestion) because they'll have senders like "MAILER-DAEMON <>" or "root" and other stuff, which will trip your enterprise mailbox anti-spam to block them...